# MySQL table has a composite primary key, but DESCRIBE TABLE only shows one being used?

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy to create some tables in a MySQL dialect. My database has a many-to-many relationship between a Projects table and a Tags table. The linking table therefore has this structure:

```
mysql> describe projects_tags;

+-------------+------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| projects_id | int  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| tags_id     | int  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+-------------+------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

...i.e., they're both being used as a composite primary key, as you'd expect. The foreign-key relationships are also apparent:

```
mysql> select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS where CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY';

+--------------------+-------------------+----------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------------+----------+
| CONSTRAINT_CATALOG | CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA | CONSTRAINT_NAME      | TABLE_SCHEMA | TABLE_NAME    | CONSTRAINT_TYPE | ENFORCED |
+--------------------+-------------------+----------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------------+----------+
| def                | uv                | projects_tags_ibfk_1 | uv           | projects_tags | FOREIGN KEY     | YES      |
| def                | uv                | projects_tags_ibfk_2 | uv           | projects_tags | FOREIGN KEY     | YES      |
+--------------------+-------------------+----------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------------+----------+
```

And it does seem to be working that way. However, I'm puzzled by the output of this command:

```
mysql> describe table projects_tags;
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table         | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | projects_tags | NULL       | index | NULL          | tags_id | 4       | NULL |    1 |   100.00 | Using index |
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
```

...specifically, `key: tags_id`. That's only half of the primary key. And presuming both `tags_id` and `projects_id` are four-byte integers, `key_len = 4` indicates that only one of them is being used.

What's going on here? Why is `describe [table_name]` yielding such different results than `describe table [table_name]`?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I understand why this is confusing. Here are some things you may not know about MySQL:

- MySQL 8.0 introduced a new statement [TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/table.html). The usage is `TABLE <tablename>;` which is equivalent to `SELECT * FROM <tablename>;`.
- [EXPLAIN and DESCRIBE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html) are more or less synonyms. You can also write it as DESC.
- If you create an index without specifying its name, the default name of the index is the same as the *first* column in that index.

So this:

```
DESCRIBE TABLE projects_id;
```

Is the same as these:

```
EXPLAIN TABLE projects_id;

DESCRIBE SELECT * FROM projects_id;

EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM projects_id;
```

In other words, you're not asking for the table definition, you're asking for the optimizer plan for querying that table.

The EXPLAIN report you saw shows that it'd doing an index-scan of all entries in the index named `tags_id`. The index may be a compound index, but still named after the first column by default.

If you want to see the table definition, use:

```
DESCRIBE projects_id;
```

But I hardly ever use DESCRIBE in that way. I would prefer to use:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE projects_id\G
```

This is better than DESCRIBE because it shows more column options, and also constraints indexes that are obscured by DESCRIBE. It also shows table options, which DESCRIBE doesn't show at all.

I use `\G` instead of `;` in the mysql client to get rid of the "box" around the result.